# Prepend additoonal html to string

Tags: javascript

I am only accepting raw js answers, jquery will be downvoted.

I have the following string, lets call this `MyHtmlAbove`:

```
<span class="fc-title-wrap"><span class="fc-title fc-sticky">Some Sample Content here</span></span>
```

I know I can do:

```
el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = myHtmlAbove;
```

What I don't know how to do now is:

Find the class `fc-title` and before the content (prepend) and icon tag: `<i class='font-awesome-here'></i>`

I am unsure if I can just use the regular raw:

```
    el.findByClassName('fc-title').prepend('<i class='font-awesome-here'></i> ')

    // Result should be:
    <span class="fc-title-wrap"><span class="fc-title fc-sticky"><i class='font-awesome-here'></i> Some Sample Content here</span></span>
```

Can some one point me in the right direction, I feel I am close.

Since I have create a temp element to do this manipulation with, I would also like to clean it up so it's not hanging out in the dom some where it shouldn't be.

Thoughts?

Comment: _"I am only accepting raw js answers, jquery will be downvoted"_: that's some opening sentence to a community that you want help from.

Comment: findByClassName returns an array.  you need to specify which one. in your example it would be [0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 document.getElementsByClassName('fc-title')[0].prepend('<i class="font-awesome-here"></i> ')

    // Result should be:
   // <span class="fc-title-wrap"><span class="fc-title fc-sticky"><i class='font-awesome-her
```

```html
<span class="fc-title-wrap"><span class="fc-title fc-sticky">Some Sample Content here</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('fc-title')[0].prepend('<i class="font-awesome-here"></i> ')
```

Comment: wow, that such a better answer

Answer (score 1):

Raw Js() version:

```js
const fcT = document.querySelector(".fc-title");
const t = fcT.innerText
const icon = "<i class='font-awesome-here'></i>"
fcT.innerHTML = icon + " " + t;

console.log(document.querySelector(".fc-title"));
```

```html
<span class="fc-title-wrap"><span class="fc-title fc-sticky">Some Sample Content here</span></span>
```